# What can stop anyone unauthorized from executing server-side functions from the client?

Tags: google-apps-script, server, client, google-apps

So I am kinda new to handling server and client programmation. But there is one security flaw that I can't get around.

For my Google Apps Script project, I have a Sidebar on Google Sheets.
The client uses a WebSocket to communicate with a third party, then I store in Google Script some informations that I wish could be given to the client when **and only when** the latter is authenticated to the WebSocket service.

This would be a breeze if Google Script supported WebSockets, [but it doesn't work atm](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/117437427), so I need to find a way to make the functions that distribute the data to the client callable only if the client is previously connected to the WebSocket.

This is a huge problem, since anyone could just go on their WebInspector, do a bit of trickery in my HTML code and place a `<button onclick=google.script.run.withSuccessHandler((data) => {//display data}).getData()>foo</button>`, and the data would be sent.

If there anyway to make this secure?